# How can I return the path of a screenshot capture to a function and return via JSON to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, casperjs

I have a PHP script that invokes a casperjs script via exec function and this is working fine.

Is it possible to return the path where I saved a screenshot via exec as JSON?

My scripts are below:

**PHP code:**

```
// Execute to CasperJS via asynchronous process
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$target = $_POST['target'];
$filename = $_POST['file'];
$retorno = array()

try {
    exec("{$casperjs_run} {$script} {$username} {$password} {$filename} 2>&1", $output);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $retorno['error404'] = "Desculpe! Não foi possivel acessar a página solicitada.";
}
// Return Data if success
// Retorna para front-end
if (empty($output)){
    $retorno['success'] = $output;
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    return false;
} else {
    $retorno['error'] = $output;
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    return false;
}
?>
```

**CasperJS code:**

```
casper.thenOpen(minhaoi, function myaccount() {
    this.capture('pic2.png');
    this.log('Acessando informações da conta, aguarde...');
    if (!this.exists(('div.panel-horizontal'))) {
        this.log(JSON.stringify("Não foi encontrado um plano colaborador, aguarde..."));
        noDetails = this.captureSelector(filename + '.png', 'div.panel-horizontal', {quality: 100});
    } else {
        casper.waitForResource("Análise de Conta", function orderDetails(details) {
            return details;
        }, function onReceive() {
            this.log('ScreenShot Begin');
            myDetails = this.captureSelector(path_images + filename + '.png', '#content', { quality: 100 } );
            this.log(' ScreenShot Done'); });
        });
     }
});

// Logout & Exit
casper.eachThen(oi_out, function () {
    this.capture('pic3.png');
    if (noDetails != "") {
        return noDetails; 
    } else {
        return myDetails;
}).run();
```

Here my JS code that receive the information from casperjs via JSON.

**Javascript Code:**

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data.success) {
        $('#retorno').html(data.success);
        $('#imagem').attr('src', '/details/' + filename);
        $('#resultado').show(); 
    }
},
error: function(data) {
    // check error
    $('#retorno').attr("class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'");
    $('#retorno').html(data.error);    
}
```

In my mind filename should be the whole name of the screenshot like this, pi9rxw2fqlh.png plus the complete path too. And display the image in the browser.

What's wrong in my approach?

Comment: [captureSelector](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#captureselector) doesn't seem to return anything but you are expecting it to

Comment: Hi @Juan Mendes, casperjs returns a object like that ====> [object Casper], currently at url...
So I'm not sure if can i decode this object using JSON.stringify.
Thanks

Comment: So, is the API (the link I sent) missing the return value? If you want to encode the object, JSON.stringfiy will work if it doesn't have circular references. If it does, you have to create a new object out of there and stringify that

Comment: `capture` as well as `captureSelector` return the `casper` instance, but that is the least of your problems. How do you invoke the casper script on the server? Do you use phantomjs web_server module or do you have a php script that `exec`s casper? Your `return` inside of the `eachThen` callback isn't doing anything. Please add the necessary code to your question.

Comment: Hi @Artjom B, I update my question to be more clear(i hope). And ask you i call casper using php_exec, above my code php, casperjs and javascript. 
I just want show the image on my webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `this.log` to actually print something, you need to set the logLevel to at least `debug` as it is the default log level. So either increase the log level `casper.options.logLevel = 'debug';` or use `this.echo` instead of `this.log`.

---

It looks like you're using [`waitForResource`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforresource) wrong. Since there can't be resources with spaces in them, you might want to checkout [`waitForText`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitfortext) under the assumption that the loaded resource adds that string to the DOM:

```
casper.waitForText("Análise de Conta", function onReceive() {
    this.log('ScreenShot Begin');
    myDetails = this.captureSelector(path_images + filename + '.png', '#content', { quality: 100 } );
    this.log(' ScreenShot Done'); });
});
```

---

`capture` as well as `captureSelector` return the `casper` instance and not the image details. So you need to pass the filename.

Since you use php's `exec` with the output array, you can `casper.echo` the filename in question with a unique beginning string (here `#noDetails#`):

```
this.captureSelector(filename + '.png', 'div.panel-horizontal', {quality: 100});
this.echo("#noDetails#" + filename + ".png");
```

In the client javascript you can then iterate over the `data.success` or `data.error` arrays and extract the filename from the match line:

```
data.success.forEach(function(line){
    if (line.indexOf("#noDetails#") === 0) {
        var filename = line.split("#noDetails#")[1];
        $('#imagem').attr('src', '/details/' + filename);
    }
});
```

With this, you can completely remove the if block from the `eachThen` callback.

---

The other option is to set the specific screenshot variable and write the JSON object in the last line.

```
this.captureSelector(filename + '.png', 'div.panel-horizontal', {quality: 100});
noDetails = filename + ".png";
```

and at the end:

```
casper.eachThen(oi_out, function () {
    this.capture('pic3.png');
    if (noDetails != "") {
        this.echo(JSON.stringify({filename:noDetails}));
    } else {
        this.echo(JSON.stringify({filename:myDetails}));
    }
});
```

On the client side, you would need to only look in the last line of the array:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data.success[data.success.length-1]);
$('#imagem').attr('src', '/details/' + obj.filename);
```

Comment: Hi @Artjom B, thanks one more time!
I have simple question, how can I finish casperjs script with status success?
If I finish casperjs script and send back the value of a variable I can parser that in the JS. I tested it with die and worked!
noDetails = (path + filename) and then this.die(noDetails) and my image displayed in the front-end.

Comment: Don't `die`, use `casper.exit` with an optional exit value.

Comment: B, doesnt work! The result always is {"success":[]}.
I don't no why.

Comment: @RodrigoAndrade `if(empty($output))` should be `if(!empty($output))`, but I don't think this will solve your problem.

Comment: B, doesn't matter the value of the $output because the exec always return the last line of the array. So I need to make casperjs exit with value of the variable myDetails or noDetails. To noDetails it's easy and work using die(), beacause die exit with error.

Comment: So, you don't use the `$output` array from `exec` anymore, but the `exec` return value? Do you write the filename as the `die` message? You can just as easily write the filename of the `myDetails` block. On second thought, your `waitForResource` is completely wrong. Have you tested it in plain casper? There cannot be a resource with spaces and the passed functions also don't make sense. Please consult the [documentation](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforresource).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58265/discussion-between-rodrigo-andrade-and-artjom-b).